# getImageData() performance

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

All I need is to get the state of a single pixel on the canvas but I've noticed that it's horribly slow.

Here's my JS

```
var state = ctx.getImageData(x,y,1,1).data;
state = 'rgba(' + state[0] + ',' + state[1] + ',' + state[2] + ',' + state[3] + ')';
return state;
```

Is there an alternative to getting the state of a single pixel on the canvas?

Comment: No, there is not other method (that I know of). What you could try, is copying only that single pixel to another 1x1px canvas first (using `drawImage`), and then only get the imagedata of that … but whether this is gonna be any “faster” isn’t a given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So how is this magic pixel changing?

Since you're doing the programming, you should likely be able to notice the activities that would change that pixel.

For example if you (or the user) are moving something across that pixel which changes that pixel, then you would be able to predict the path of any object over the pixel (or notice the user is moving something over that pixel).

Anyway, if `.getImageData` is dragging down your performance, my suggestion would be to set up a .requestAnimationFrame loop and check for changes on that pixel at larger intervals. If you're checking every 1/60th of a second, maybe just check every 5/60th of a second.